# Using Google Cloud Storage to host images for an image sharing site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am building an image sharing site and I want the images uploaded to be saved on Cloud Storage. I'm at the POC stage and would like to know the following:

- Once an image is uploaded could I generate a image URL that could be sent to my UI service which could be used to render the image on the front end?
- I want to prevent the user from downloading the image from the usual methods (right clicking save as / right click open in new tab). Could this be done from Cloud Storage itself or should it be implemented in the front end using overlays or watermarks etc.
- In such a scenario where we have a specific download button to download the image, what is the best way to implement this? Do I download the image on the backend server and then send it to the front end using something like `gsutils`? Or can the front end directly request the image from Cloud Storage?

Also open to any other alternatives that accomplish the above. Thanks!

Comment: If you send the data to the client (the web browser of the user), the data is already on the client. There will always be ways to store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question required engineering and architecture in the cloud. So, I can provide your some insight, but you need to go deeper in each part to achieve correctly your site

Firstly, the users mustn't directly access to the Cloud Storage bucket, either you need to set it public, and anyone can access to all the content. When a user need to read or write a file, use the [signed Url mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

When a new image is uploaded, you need to [trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) (an event is emitted when the file is uploaded and you can plug a function (or a [pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)) on this event). **Why?** because the overlay/watermark/low resolution version need to be done server side. You can perform this when you display the picture on the site. But it reduce the latency for the user. That's why I recommend you to perform this new image version when the file is uploaded with a Cloud Functions and to store it in Cloud Storage (in another directory, like `thumbnail`)

And thus, you need to save 2 paths in database: the original image, and the processed image. On the site, you display the processed image, when the download button is clicked, you generate a signed URL to download the original image.

---

The ACL is going to be deprecated, or at least, not recommended by Google. Having a uniform authorization policy (based on IAM service) is the recommended best practice by Google.

But you can achieve the same things
[image]

But, in this cases, you can't limit the access to the original version directory and to the thumbnail directory. Users have free access to all, to download, upload and delete what they want.

If it's your use case, perfect, else... use signed Url!

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your answer. Its pretty much I wanted. Want to clarify one small thing about signed URLs. If I use `gsutil acl ch -g my-domain.org:R gs://bucket` to give my domain read permission to my bucket, and if I use the authorization URL in my `src` tag, will the images be accessible only from my domain? Thereby eliminating the need for a Signed URL?

Comment: I edited my answer. I can't recommend to use the ACL. It depends of your use case.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Very much appreciated